# Difference between a directory on two remote branches on git

Tags: git, compare, diff

I'd like to find the difference between a given directory on two remote branches. Currently I can compare the two branches like so

```
gitk --left-right remote/branch1 remote/branch2
```

But that's giving me way too much information. I'd like to limit the diff to one directory, `foobar`. Is this possible?

Comment: try `gitk --left-right remote/branch1:foobar remote/branch2:foobar`

Comment: @hjpotter92 It did not work. Message: no commits selected.

Comment: Why are you using `--left-right` here? Without a symmetric difference (three-dot) operator it will show everything as being on the right. In any case if you just want a diff between (all or parts of) two commits, `git diff` is the tool for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify path as the last parameter. `--` is optional, but use it to make sure the path is seperated from preceding options.

```
gitk --left-right remote/branch1 remote/branch2 -- foobar
```